# How did they get the slider to work like this

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-cycle2

How did this website get the slider to work like this?

http://www.wistar.org/

I'm making one myself but the next/previous images you can see for about 1/4th of the whole is what keeps me wondering. All I accomplished is to just next/previous with a 0 cycle time but that fade of the next/previous image is what keeps me wondering.

Anyone has suggestions on how to approach this method?

Thanks in advance.

Jsfiddle isn't the original since I can't post it due to it being wordpress php(made this quickly):

jsfiddle.net/RkgrG/40/ (Not enough rep to link sorry)

Comment: Can you show us what you have attempted so far?

Comment: Of course one moment.

Comment: Are you referring to the way the image becomes greyscale when you move to another one?

Comment: Post you code directly on here and also in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Adsy One Issue i'm using wordpress so you won't have any real example. So I suppose I can give you this which I quickly changed.(See post).  Archer I'm reffering to the two images on the sides that you can see before you cick on next/previous. So you have an idea of what's coming next and then when you actually click it the current would go to the left or right according that what you clicked (Next/Previous).

Comment: I don't see them - the slider fills the width of my browser so I see just the 1 image and nothing of the others.

Comment: @user3121076 : +1 for taking the effort in creating everything from scratch.

Comment: @Archer Do you mean the jsfiddle or the real one? I suggest checking out the jsfiddle since that's I suppose the best functioning one the real one needs to be polished in compatibility more anyway.

RoyMJ Thank you! :D

Comment: I just made a small change to the css, and there's an issue with the first and last images, but is this the kind of thing you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/RkgrG/43/

Comment: @user3121076 take a look at this gallery I've created: http://jsbin.com/UyIceLA/1/

Comment: Yea @Archer that's it! Thanks! Roko C. Buljan, yes that's what I have to make from what Archer gave me it'll be a long run, I hope I can manage to do it.

Comment: As well as I MUST use Cycle2 since it's an assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

pastebin.com/ga3CGtH4

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle2/20130801/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle2/20130409/jquery.cycle2.carousel.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            #home-rotator-container { width:100%; overflow:hidden; position:relative; }
            #home-rotator .cycle-slideshow { width:3300px; }
            #home-rotator .cycle-slideshow img  { width: 1100px; height: 400px; }
            #home-rotator .cycle-slideshow {
                position:absolute;
                top:0;
                left:0;
            }
        </style>

        <div id="home-rotator-container">
            <div id="home-rotator">    
                <div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-fx="carousel" data-cycle-speed="800" data-cycle-carousel-visible="3">
                    <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/beach1.jpg">
                    <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/beach2.jpg">
                    <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/beach3.jpg">
                    <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/beach4.jpg">
                    <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/beach5.jpg">
                    <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/beach6.jpg">  
                </div>            
            </div><!-- /#home-rotator -->
        </div><!-- /#home-rotator-container -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // function that determines offset
            function positionRotator()
            {
                var rotator_size = 1100;
                var initial_width = $(window).width();          
                var offset = (rotator_size - ((initial_width - rotator_size) / 2)) * -1;
                $("#home-rotator .cycle-slideshow").css("left",offset);            
            }          

            // do initial positioning
            positionRotator();      

            // re-position if screen is resized
            $(window).resize(function() {
              positionRotator();                      
            });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
if you change sizes remember to change the offset too:

```
var rotator_size = 1100;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need I just have some issues with my css but i'll figure it out!

Comment: :) if you can accept the question or at least vote it

Comment: There you go buddy, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'll create one *from scratch* cause I need it for my project I'm doing right now

Still making the JS logic, but to show you the first steps:

***[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ixAJUREZ/1/edit)***

HTML:

```
<div id="galleryOverflow">  
  <div id="galleryCenter">    
    <div id="gallery">

      <span style="background-image:url(//placehold.it/960x540/ada);">1</span>
      <span style="background-image:url(//placehold.it/960x540/fbi);">2</span>
      <span style="background-image:url(//placehold.it/960x540/fof);">3</span>
      <span style="background-image:url(//placehold.it/960x540/ie5);">4</span>

    </div>    
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#galleryOverflow{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:540px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:#ddd;
}
#galleryCenter{
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:960px;
  background:#eee;
  height:540px;
}
#gallery{
  position:absolute;
  height:540px;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  white-space:nowrap;
  font-size:0; /* remove right 4px margin */
}
#gallery span{
  font-size:18px; /* reset font */
  vertical-align:top;
  display:inline-block;
  height:540px;
  width:100%;
  background: transparent none no-repeat center center;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

- The base is to have a 100% width element with `overflow:hidden` which will prevent the page to show horizontal scrollbars,
- than inside that one you put a centered 960px element
- and inside that centered element, you absolute position an element that will hold all your  `SPAN` slides.
- To position the SPANs horizontally you need to set to their parent the `white-space:nowrap;` and to remove 4px margin gap the font-size to `0`
- Than for your SPANs you need to reset the font size and to allow to have text inside them set the `vertical-align` property.
- Now your `SPAN` slides extend faaar on the right side but the center one (currently the first one) will be always centered with the page even on page resize.
- Now all you need to to with JS is to take the last image, place it in-front of the first one, and logically : move the `.css()` of the entire SPANs container (the `#gallery`) to `-960px` making the first image visible again.

***[DEMO WITH JS/jQuery](http://jsbin.com/ixAJUREZ/3/edit)***

```
$(function(){ // DOM ready

    var $gallery = $('#gallery');
    var $slide   = $("span", $gallery);
    var W = $('#galleryCenter').width(); // 960
    var N = $slide.length; // number of slides     

    // Prepare gallery:
    // Take last slide and set in front of all
    $slide.last().prependTo($gallery); 
    // Now move gallery to show again the first slide
    $gallery.css({left:-W}); 


    $('#prev, #next').click(function(){

      $slide = $("span", $gallery); // recatch all elements

      if( !$gallery.is(':animated') ){ // Prevent clicks if gall is animated

        if(this.id == "next"){

          var $first = $slide.eq( 0 );
          $first.clone().appendTo( $gallery );
          $gallery.animate({ left: '-='+W },800, function(){
            $first.remove(); // we don't need it any more
            // but now we have a 960px gap so:
            $(this).css({left: -W }); // reset to -960
          });

        }else{ // == "prev"

          var $last = $slide.eq( N-1 ); // N-1 is the last one
          $last.clone().prependTo( $gallery );
          // now that we prepended the lasts element the gallery jumped 
          // to +960 cause of that insertion, let's reset it:
          $gallery.css({ left: -W*2 });
          // and let's animate
          $gallery.animate({left:'+='+W},800, function(){
            $last.remove(); // we don't need it any more
          });

        }
      }

    });

});
```

***[DEMO WITH AUTOSLIDE AND PAUSE ON HOVER](http://jsbin.com/IqUTUre/1/edit)***

To make it autoslide you need an `setInverval` so for that we need a new `var`

```
var intv;
```

and below the "prev next clicks function" this code:

```
  // //////////////////////
  // LOOP AUTOMATICALLY
  function auto(){
    intv = setInterval(function(){
      $('#next').click(); // Do a "next" click
    }, 3200 );// every 3200ms
  }
  auto(); // start loop
```

To pause the loop on **mouseenter** add:

```
  $('#galleryOverflow').hover(function(e){
    return e.type=="mouseenter" ? clearinterval(intv) : auto();
  });
```

***[FINAL DEMO EXAMPLE](http://jsbin.com/ixAJUREZ/5/edit)***

Comment: I'm active and watching, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Man what a challenge this is i'm trying this with cycle2 and wordpress and a preset CSS+plugins.js file in which the whole cycle 2 is thrown in ..sigh but i'll try and follow your steps(I'm a student+intern building a site for a company).

Comment: @user3121076 done wit the JS. Soon adding the functions to autoslide and pause on hover.

Comment: This is amazing! The only Issue i'd have if i'd reassemble this is knowing what I need and not because i'm pretty sure Cycle 2 supports most of the JS you wrote I just don't know what exactly and since I unfortunately am Obliged to use Cycle 2 i'm stuck here wondering >.<

But I want you to know that I sincerely appreciate all the effort you did and once i'm done with this Cycle 2 project i'll definitely use your code as a bridge in my thoughts for whenever I make my next slider!

Does the link expire?

Comment: @user3121076 no, the link will stay. I'm done with the auto-slide, now I'll do the opacity thing

Comment: Thank you so much I favorited it and I saw what you did and it's also exactly what I need although Cycle 2 is in the way but either way whenever I work on my own site i'll do it on your way!

Comment: @user3121076 you don't need to use *my way*, it was just to show you the logic behind this infinite scrolling sliders. You use whatever you want. It's good to know how to setup a plugin, but it's also priceless to know how to build one ;) Once I'm done with my project I'll drop you a link.

Answer (score -1):

If you talking about image, it swap B/W images and color images fading them out

example : 
http://www.wistar.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/desat/home/masthead_images/cell.jpg
http://www.wistar.org/sites/default/files/home/masthead_images/cell.jpg

for the box that slide content: it slide between divs and images simultaneously.

Comment: Yea but what I mean is that you see about 1/4th of the upcoming/previous image, I don't know how to approach this.

Comment: Terrible answer - sorry.  "just swap" and "is easy" are not constructive or helpful.  It also doesn't "just swap" images - it fades them which is a bit more involved than changing a src attribute.

Comment: create a div that contains the slider larger then the image, then you might see a piece of the next image. Then apply left position to like 40px for example, and you will see a piece of previous one. Adjust left position and you've done. @Archer you right sorry!Fixed it

Comment: @StefanoCerelli Regardless of the answer thanks for the tip, i've tried it just now unfortunately what happened was that the image was pushed out of the div and didn't show up next to it at all.(If you feel like it inspect element on the original one and try it as well).

EDIT: What i've noticed so far is when you click next/previous on my version you see a huge gap when the current one dissapears and the next/previous one appears. Any idea where it came from?

Comment: Depends on how your slider works, i remember i did i on jCarousel lite in the past and it worked well. if you can provide a fiddle with your code i can try to look at it.

Comment: There is a fiddle up there but it has no link probably why you didn't notice it(I lack the rep to link more) and it's a quickly made one because the actual presentation is in wordpress so I can't put it on jsfiddle due to the php.

Comment: sry didn't read your edit :S looking at it now.

Comment: With cycle is better if you work directly on the plugin code, i think,  i'm at work now and can't waste too much time on this, meanwhile try to use jcarousel-lite (http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/) and just apply, this: pastebin.com/QDWCvNky i'll sort your cycle tonight. If it was useful please, upvote my answer thanks :)


edit: you can initialize jcarousel-lite like this:
<script type="text/javascript">

$(".carousel").jCarouselLite({
      btnNext: ".next",
      btnPrev: ".prev",
      scroll: 1
 });

</script>

Comment: I completely agree i'd use others if I could but it's an assignment and I MUST use cycle 2 unfortunately..